# Enhanced Dynamic Content block

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic

I was looking into this Enhanced Dynamic content feature within Content Builder and viewed the Youtube video about it. It mentions that everything is setup into a CSV file with content (text, HTML, etc).

Is there a way to create that csv file having images and links set up ? Or no?

I'm unable to locate a sample file I can reference to start off this process and how things are structured.

Is there a sample format someone can share?

Thank you

Comment: Again, welcome! Thank you for "listening" to the comments on your answer to the other question and posting this new question. I don't have the knowledge to answer this question. But If you'd like - as a further way to let potential helpers know that you also searched on SFSE - you could [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/355578/edit) your question to link to that other question, and state that you looked at it but it was unhelpful. An easy way to link to another question is to go to the question, click "Share" under the question, then click "Copy Link". I hope someone helps you.

Answer (score 0):

How to use Enhanced Dynamic Content blocks.

Illustrating pull country flags based on country names. [Country_code, Flag_url]

1. Upload a CSV under below path [example [here]](https://we.tl/t-4c9YpWMbeh)
   *Content builder > Create > **Upload** > Enhanced Dynamic Content* 
   Follow the wizard to as per the requirement.
2. Then you need to create a Enhanced dynamic content block using below option.
   *Content builder > Create > **Content Blocks** > Enhanced Dynamic Content* 


   **Reference image 01** = [image]
   **Reference image 02** = [image]
   **Sample CSV screenshot** = [image]